# Timer to start car engine

Tags: automotive, automation

For some reasons, i'd like to start my car at some specific times (e.g. from 11:00pm to 11:10pm, then from 5:00am to 5:10am). Are there any simple ways of achieving this? I thought of Arduino but I don't have much equipment at hand presently. Maybe a relay activated by two alarm clocks and a timer set on 10min?

Comment: what would the relay operate?

Comment: An alarm clock can not be hacked like that. You will need some sort of microcontroller.

Comment: Or you could do some janky MacGyver trick on a $50 Viper 1-way Remote Start by having a "finger" somehow push down on the start button.

Comment: If this is related to temperature - I have a small 400W heater fitted under the bonnet which comes on via a time switch and warms the engine bay nicely ready for the first start of the day. Works well in Switzerland for cold mornings...

Comment: I'm sure some alarm clocks can be hacked like that. Of course it's still more efficient to make your own thingy.

Comment: The first secret of committing the perfect crime: Don't use the interwebs to plan your alibi.

Comment: Note that in some jurisdictions leaving a vehicle unattended with the engine running is illegal.  Check your local laws before doing this.

Comment: @jsotola: the ignition.

Comment: @anderstood: That's jsotola's point: it would have to turn on ignition and the starter and disconnect the starter when the engine is running.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a remote start kit, a spare key fob, and a switch to let your Arduino (or whatever) "press" the start button on the fob at the desired time.

Wire a spare GPIO on the Arduino to a MOSFET and the contacts in the key fob, and create a program / sketch that toggles the pin at the desired time.

If you don't want to get a remote start kit, you'll wind up having to build basically the same thing, including bypassing the anti-theft system (if present) and/or leaving a key in the ignition. Also, I hope this is for a car with an automatic transmission. You don't want your car charging into the nearest obstacle on its own if you accidentally leave it in gear. (As a manual transmission-equipped car should *always* be parked.)

I'd also add a way to make sure that the car isn't already running before activating. Maybe add an ADC connected to the tachometer signal, or read from a switched pin in the fuse box?